# Snappy app font misconfiguration

Tags: 18.04, fonts, snap

The Ubuntu snap store Snappy does not display correctly western chars
[image]

I ran it from XFCE terminal with following command

```
env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/snap-store_snap-store.desktop /snap/bin/snap-store %U


then got some errors:
```

12:03:58:0663 Gs enabled plugins: odrs, rewrite-resource, snap, icons, key-colors, key-colors-metadata 12:03:58:0663 Gs disabled plugins: appstream, desktop-categories, desktop-menu-path, dpkg, dummy, epiphany, fedora-pkgdb-collections, generic-updates, hardcoded-blacklist, hardcoded-featured, hardcoded-popular, modalias, os-release, provenance, provenance-license, repos, shell-extensions 12:03:58:0961 Gs failed to create an app for */*/*/*/system/* 12:03:59:0033 Gs updates-shell: failed to get updates: no plugin could handle get-updates 12:03:59:0034 Gs failed to create an app for */*/*/*/system/* 12:03:59:0034 Gs failed to get system app 12:03:59:0034 Gs failed to convert URL to GsApp: no application was created for running url-to-app with dedupe-flags=7 with refine-flags=require-license,require-url,require-size,require-version,require-history,require-setup-action,require-origin,require-related,require-menu-path,require-allow-packages,require-provenance,require-icon,require-permissions,require-origin-hostname,require-runtime,require-screenshots,require-categories,require-project-group,require-developer-name,require-kudos,content-rating with timeout=60 with search=file:///home/user/%25U on plugin=snap 12:03:59:0039 Gs Only 0 apps for recent list, hiding 12:03:59:0312 Gs hiding category audio-video featured applications: found only 0 to show, need at least 9 12:03:59:0312 Gs hiding category productivity featured applications: found only 0 to show, need at least 9 12:03:59:0469 GLib g_path_get_basename: assertion 'file_name != NULL' failed 12:03:59:0469 GLib g_regex_match_full: assertion 'string != NULL' failed 12:03:59:0469 GLib g_path_get_basename: assertion 'file_name != NULL' failed 12:03:59:0469 GLib g_regex_match_full: assertion 'string != NULL' failed 12:03:59:0659 GLib g_variant_new_variant: assertion 'value != NULL' failed 12:03:59:0659 GLib g_variant_new_variant: assertion 'value != NULL' failed 12:03:59:0662 Gs not GsPlugin error g-io-error-quark:35: Invalid string value converting to GVariant 12:03:59:0662 Gs not handling error failed for action refine: Invalid string value converting to GVariant 12:03:59:0674 GLib g_variant_new_variant: assertion 'value != NULL' failed 12:03:59:0674 GLib g_variant_new_variant: assertion 'value != NULL' failed 12:03:59:0679 Gs not GsPlugin error g-io-error-quark:35: Invalid string value converting to GVariant 12:03:59:0679 Gs not handling error failed for action refine: Invalid string value converting to GVariant 12:03:59:0716 GLib g_variant_new_variant: assertion 'value != NULL' failed 12:03:59:0716 GLib g_variant_new_variant: assertion 'value != NULL' failed 12:03:59:0718 Gs not GsPlugin error g-io-error-quark:35: Invalid string value converting to GVariant 12:03:59:0718 Gs not handling error failed for action refine: Invalid string value converting to GVariant 12:04:00:0238 GsPluginSnap Failed to load snap icon: local snap has no icon 12:04:00:0466 GsPluginSnap Failed to load snap icon: local snap has no icon 12:04:00:0747 GsPluginSnap Failed to load snap icon: local snap has no icon

Do I need reinstall Snappy, and how about all installed apps does they remains?